# What is difference between Lightning Wallet and Lightning Node?

Tags: wallet, lightning-network, terminology

I am confused with the terminology of lightning node vs and wallet, as I see that each individual can run its own wallet like eclair so does that mean the person running a wallet is also running a lightning node ?

Can single lightning node be used by multiple people to receive and send Payments ?

Comment: Single node can be used by multiple people. Examples: https://github.com/lnbits/lnbits https://github.com/guggero/faraday/

Comment: @Prayank the way lnbits works seems it creates a layer above lightning node via api structure and allows multiple wallets, but if we think of core lightning node it seems not supporting multiple wallets.

Comment: TBH I haven't used any of these and mostly involved in on-chain projects. Devs who are involved in LN projects will be the best people to comment on it. However I remember reading about these, they looked interesting and relevant to your question so commented.

Comment: Ok got it appreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, a wallet is a piece of software that manages the user's key material, tracks their balance, and facilitates payments. On the Lightning Network, this means that a wallet must also be able to manage channels. These tasks could be handled by a thin client, under the assumption that it trusts a service provider for providing certain information.

Node software usually includes wallet capabilities but indicates further properties, such as being online at all times, participating in network gossip, and keeping track of the state of Bitcoin's blockchain by being directly to a co-hosted full node.